# Ionic app not looking the same in Android Device as in Desktop Browser

Tags: android, angularjs, frameworks, ionic-framework

I'm really new to ionic/AngularJS/Cordova app development so I'm facing some issues that someone with quite better comprehension on the subject than me could easily fix.

I successfully installed all the components needed to start developing with the already mentioned frameworks.

After installation, I started playing a little bit with some examples and managed to create a really simple app that just had a side menu.

When I was testing my really simple app using ionic serve command, the app launched in my browser (as it should) and worked they way I was expecting to.

My problem comes when I type the ionic run android command.

The app gets built and everything and after that it gets installed in my Android Virtual Device, which later launches the app with no errors.

But the thing is that the app running in my AVD doesn't look the same as in my browser. It looks as if some styles were missing or something.

I know it might be something really easy to fix that I'm just missing.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ionic framework renders the UI layout based on the platform the app is run to provide close to native look and feel. This is as per the design of the framework. If you want to control the rendering, i.e., to have the same look and feel across all platforms, you can make use of the `$ionicConfigProvider` service in your app and make appropriate changes. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/

Also to get a feel of how the UI looks in iOS and Android side by side you can use the below command
`ionic serve --lab`

Read this http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html for more options on ionic cli